# how to publish react native application without expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing an application using react native and PHP.
And to see the modifications, I used expo (so each time I have to connect my phone with a USB cable)
Now, I'm looking for a solution to install the application on my phone (without using cable ) and share it with my colleagues !!

Your suggestions please

Comment: you should build the app through react native cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
expo-cli build: android
```

command and expo will build your app to your expo account for that you have to your expo account and the further process will handle by the expo.

This process will take some time after that you can download your .apk file from your expo account's builds section.